# Angular 2 - Global Error handler getting executed only when the error is NOT catched

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling, angular2-services

In my Angular application, there is a global error handler and a service responsible for making `http` calls, having return type as `Observable<any>`. Some services have handled the errors explicitly and some not.

For those, which has not been catched, the global error (having class '*CustomErrorHandler*') runs fine. For the service calls, which has been handled and catched gracefully, the global error doesn't seem to fire.

> **My question**: Is there a way to execute the global error handling irrespective of whether the http service calls has been handled or not?

**custom-error-handler.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    handleError(error) {
        error = error || new Error('There was an unexpected error');
        const loggingService: LoggerService = this.injector.get(LoggerService);
        const location = this.injector.get(LocationStrategy);
        const message = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        const url = location instanceof PathLocationStrategy
        ? location.path() : '';

        // get the stack trace, lets grab the last 10 stacks only
        StackTrace.fromError(error).then(stackframes => {
            const stackString = stackframes
                .splice(0, 20)
                .map((sf) => {
                    return sf.toString();
                }).join('\n');

            // log with logging service
            loggingService.error({ message, url, stack: stackString });

        });

        throw error;
    }

}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthService {
    login(emailAddress: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
        if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
        return Observable.of(true);
        }

        return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.http.get('http://someurl/login')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
              data => {
                observer.next(this.isAuthorized);
                observer.complete();
              }, err => {
                observer.error(err);
              }
           );
        });
    }

  }
```

**my-component.ts**

```
import { UserAuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private authService: UserAuthService) {}

    handleLogin() {
        this.authService.login(formValues.emailAddress, formValues.password)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('Logged In');
            }, err => {
                console.log('Logging Failed'); 
                // Global Error DOESN'T fire here as the Error has been handled
            });
    }

    handleLoginPart2() {
        this.authService.login(formValues.emailAddress, formValues.password)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('Logged In');
            }); // Global Error does fire here as the Error has NOT been handled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue myself, by creating a `HttpClient` which inherits from `Http`.

By doing this I am able to handle the error gracefully.

**http-client.service.ts**

```
import { ConnectionBackend, Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient extends Http {
  http;

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.get(url, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(errorRes: Response | any) {
    return Observable.throw(retError);
  }
}
```